# error in retrieving field, javascript minifier error

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, liferay, syntax-error

I know this question may have many duplicates by now, but I encountered this while working on my liferay project...

I'm placing retrieved database fields in my jsp by doing this,,

```
<portlet:resourceURL  var="imageResourceURL1">
<portlet:param name="image" value="nbi"/>
</portlet:resourceURL>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkUploads(){
        <% 
            Blob nbi=null, omb=null, san=null, cs=null, birthCert=null, affid=null, waiver=null;
            try{

                attachments a = attachmentsLocalServiceUtil.getAttachmentsByUserId();

                nbi = a.getNbi_clearance();
                omb = a.getOmbudsman_clearance();
                san = a.getSandiganbayan_clearance();
                cs = a.getCivil_service_clearance();
                birthCert = a.getBirthcertificate();
                affid = a.getAffidavit_of_no_relation();
                waiver = a.getAuth_waiver();

                out.println(nbi);
                out.println(omb);
                out.println(san);
                out.println(cs);
                out.println(birthCert);
                out.println(affid);
                out.println(waiver);

            }catch(Exception e){
                out.println(e);
            }
        %>

        /* check nbi */  
        if(nbi == null || nbi == ""){
            $(".nbiUpload").empty().append(
            '<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="<portlet:namespace />nbiFile" id="nbi" style="display:none" />'
            +'<input type="text" id="nbiFilename" />'
            +'<button type="submit" id="nbiBrowse" onclick="$("#nbi").click()">Browse</button>'
            +'<button type="button" id="nbiUpload" name="<portlet:namespace />nbisubmit">Upload</button>'
            +'<script type="text/javascript">'
                +'$("#nbi").change(function(e) {'
                    +'$("#nbiFilename").val(this.files[0].name);'
                +'});'
                +'$("#nbiUpload").click(function(event){'
                    +'event.preventDefault();'
                +'});'
                +'$("#nbiBrowse").click(function(event){'
                    +'event.preventDefault();'
                +'});'
            +'< /script>');
        }else{
            $(".nbiUpload").empty().append(
            '<a id="nbiclearance" href='<%=imageResourceURL1.toString()%>' rel="lightbox" style="cursor:pointer">'
            +'<img src='<%=imageResourceURL1.toString()%>' alt="no Image" id="img_nbi_clearance" style="height:100px;width:130px;cursor:pointer;" border="0"></a>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

what I can't understand are the errors, Im getting errors such as these,,

```
18:28:13,916 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-160][MinifierUtil:111] 3: 38: missing ; before statement
18:28:13,917 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-160][MinifierUtil:111] 7: 33: missing ; before statement
18:28:13,918 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-160][MinifierUtil:111] 24: 10: syntax error
18:28:13,918 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-160][MinifierUtil:111] 26: 39: missing ) after argument list
```

maybe I just errors in syntax, so please help me with it.. :)

Comment: in the `else` part I guess you missed + : `else{
            $(".nbiUpload").empty().append(
            '<a id="nbiclearance" href=' + <%=imageResourceURL1.toString()%> + ' rel="lightbox" style="cursor:pointer">'
            +'<img src=' + <%=imageResourceURL1.toString()%> + ' alt="no Image" id="img_nbi_clearance" style="height:100px;width:130px;cursor:pointer;" border="0"></a>');
        }`

Comment: it removed some errors I think sir,,, did you spot other errors ? I still have some syntax errors left sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving the exact location of the problem (which is hard when all one can do is read some code that generates output), here's how I'd like you to debug it yourself: Your problems seem to be with the Minifier - that's the component that removes superfluous spaces and linebreaks and assumes that your script code is valid. A nice trick to get around this is to remove the `<script>` tag temporarily. Replace it with `(script)` and `(/script)`, open the page, search for this temporary content and the minifier will not touch it. But now you can see what exactly gets rendered into your HTML document.

Typical issues are: You should consider to escape various values for output: Filenames or other data from your database might contain spaces, quotes or other special characters that mess with your output and terminate strings in unexpected places.

Another option is: add `?strip=0` to the URL - this should disable Liferay's JS minifier. You'll still have invalid JS code, but now the browser's Developer Tools can point you to the questionable place directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add "**+**" in the else part of the script..

```
if(nbi == null || nbi == ""){
    $(".nbiUpload").empty().append(
    '<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="<portlet:namespace />nbiFile" id="nbi" style="display:none" />'
    +'<input type="text" id="nbiFilename" />'
    +'<button type="submit" id="nbiBrowse" onclick="$("#nbi").click()">Browse</button>'
    +'<button type="button" id="nbiUpload" name="<portlet:namespace />nbisubmit">Upload</button>'
    +'<script type="text/javascript">'
        +'$("#nbi").change(function(e) {'
            +'$("#nbiFilename").val(this.files[0].name);'
        +'});'
        +'$("#nbiUpload").click(function(event){'
            +'event.preventDefault();'
        +'});'
        +'$("#nbiBrowse").click(function(event){'
            +'event.preventDefault();'
        +'});'
    +'< /script>');
}
else
{
    $(".nbiUpload").empty().append(
    '<a id="nbiclearance" href=' + '<%=imageResourceURL1.toString()%>' + ' rel="lightbox" style="cursor:pointer">'
    +'<img src=' + '<%=imageResourceURL1.toString()%>' + ' alt="no Image" id="img_nbi_clearance" style="height:100px;width:130px;cursor:pointer;" border="0"></a>');
}
```

Comment: I did that, but some errors are left,, I can't spot any more,, aside from the improperly closed script tag,,